# Dynamic SQL Statement is too long

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using quite a long dynamic SQL Statement (a bit more than 13000 characters) but when I am trying to execute it, I am noticing that the exec isn't reading the statement completly and cuts the last part off.

I am using:

```
DECLARE @Statement nvarchar(max)
SET @Statement = N'[LONG STATEMENT]'
EXEC (@Statement)
```

I did notice, that it could read even less characters, if I am not using the the brackets in `EXEC (@Statement)`

I also tried using `EXEC sp_executesql @Statement`
It just stops reading the statement after 12482 characters...
I have the problems with SQL-Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2014

EDIT: OK, now I noticed something different. It seems, that the lenght itself of the statement is not exactly the problem. As I mentioned in a comment below, I am using this long dynamic sql statement, because I am creating an update script, which adds a new stored procedure and within this procedure I am using table names, which can differ. So I created variables, which contain the table names and used these variables with the dynamic sql statement, so I don't need to change the table names within the procedures and functions I am adding with this update script, but just changing the content of the variables.
However, if I am NOT using these variables and use the table names "hardcoded" in the statement, the statement can be executed successfully...

Comment: sounds horrific if you're running a dynamic sql statement that is that long. what is the reasoning for using dynamic sql? and can you not break the statement into smaller statements?

Comment: The limit is around 2GB so that is not the issue.  How are you determining its truncation point? Note that SSMS results views have configurable limits as the the maximum data they will display.

Comment: *"I am noticing that the exec isn't reading the statement completly and cuts the last part off"* >> Tell us how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: If you're looking at the results in SSMS then it may well look truncated. It's very unlikely to actually be truncating data however, it's a display limit in SSMS.

Comment: @Tanner I am using dynamic sql because I need to create an update script, which creates a new stored procedure which is quite long. However the stored procedure is using table names, which could differ depending on the system the procedure is running on. And since I don't want to change the table names every time within the procedure itself, I created variables, which contains the name of the tables and use them in the dynamic sql statement, where I am creating the procedure.

At TT. the error message says, that it can't find a scalar variable, because the name of the variable is cut off.

Comment: Maybe next helps: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/varcharmax-field-cutting-off-data-after-8000-characters-sql-server-2008

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce a problem for a shorter version of the script (easier to analyse)? Are you sure that this script has ever worked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the answer is here:

> So I created variables, which contain the table names and used these
>   variables with the dynamic sql statement, so I don't need to change
>   the table names within the procedures and functions I am adding with
>   this update script, but just changing the content of the variables.

I guess, your dynamic `T-SQL` statement is built using string concatenation. So, let's say we have something like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLSTatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @TableName01 NVARCHAR(128) = 'T01';
DECLARE @TableName02 NVARCHAR(128) = 'T02';

DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(4000) = REPLICATE(N'X', 4000);

SET @DynamicSQLSTatement =  @TableName01 + @TSQL + @TableName02;
```

We have three `short` strings (length < max) and when they are concatenated, we expect that the new `NVARCHAR(MAX)` value will be capable of storing the whole new string (it is with `max` length, after all).

So, the following statement will give as `T02`, right?

```
SELECT RIGHT(@DynamicSQLSTatement, 3);
```

But no, the output is `XXX`. So, the question is why the whole concatenation text is not preserved?

When you are concatenating `nvarchar(1-4000)` strings they output string is not converted to `max` if it is not possible to store all the data.

In order to fix this, we can cast the first part of the string to `nvarchar(max)`:

```
SET @DynamicSQLSTatement =  CAST(@TableName01 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + @TSQL + @TableName02

SELECT RIGHT(@DynamicSQLSTatement, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine your hitting a limit of about 16K (8K used to be the most data you could hold in a variable before nvarchar(max) etc was invented. You could try using varchar(max) instead of nvarchar as that will be half the size (unicode is 16-bit, ascii is 8-bit). I have a feeling that won't help much though.

Really though, you're hitting this issue because whatever you're trying to do shouldn't really be done like that, super long SQL statements are a sign that you've gone down the wrong path. Find a way to break down your query or operations. If this is a query, consider if you could restrict your data set over a few steps rather than in one query.